# ApplicationInsight: where to view Trace and Error on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am logging the exeception from JavaScript using the following statements

```
appInsights.trackPageView({ name: pageName });
```

I can view this on portal

`appInsights.trackTrace({ message: message });`
Where do i look for traces?

```
appInsights.trackException(new Error(errorMessage), pageName, methodName, null);
```

where do i look for Exceptions?

I have this statements in try catch and no errors are occuring on client side.
I know there is lage/delay for this to show up on azure portal, but its been more than hour, by the way trackPageView are showing up.

Comment: which version of app-insights-for-js package are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Traces** and **Exceptions** logs should be shown in the **traces table** and **exceptions table** in application insights respectively.

Nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> Logs -> select traces table or exceptions table, then select a proper "Time range", click the run button. See the screenshot as below:

[image]

Note: if you still cannot see these logs, please tell us which version of app-insights-for-js package you're using, as well as the sample code you're using.